# Concatenating IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> values into string using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

Given `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, I'm trying to use linq to concatenate the values into one string.

My Attempt:

```
string path = attributes.Aggregate((current, next) => "@" + current.Key + "=" + current.Value + " and @" + next.Key + "=" + next.Value);
```

This produces the error:

> Cannot convert expression type '`string`' to return type '`KeyValuePair<string,string>`'

Is there a more effiecient way to do this in linq?

The full method...

```
public IEnumerable<XmlNode> GetNodes(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> attributes) {
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string path = attributes.Aggregate((current, next) => "@" + current.Key + "=" + current.Value + " and @" + next.Key + "=" + next.Value);
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, path);

    return stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>().Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var strings = attributes.Select(kvp => string.Format("@{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
string path = string.Join(" and ", strings);
```

Comment: Needed to convert `string.ToArray()`

Comment: @bflemi3, not in .NET 4.0 or higher ;)

Comment: well that explains it, I'm on 3.5 :)

Comment: @MatthewKennedy, because in 3.5 and earlier there is no `String.Join` overload that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`, it only accepts an array.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I know that, was wondering why he was not on 4.0/4.1/4.5.

Comment: @MatthewKennedy, you don't always get to choose... there are often business reasons that require you to target an older version.

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = String.Join("@",attributes.Select(kv=>kv.Key+"="+kv.Value));
```

Comment: @Rawling absolutely **no**, output will be `keyone=valueone@keytwo=valuetwo@keythree=valuethree`

Comment: Aaah sorry you're right, it won't be that bad, but it still misses out the "and"s.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use aggregate to make a string you need to use the seeded overload of aggregate
if you use the none seeded version then all the types in the call need to be the same.

Comment: so then `attributes.Aggregate("",(current, next) => current + " and @" + next.Key + "=" + next.Value); But that produces... ` and @zone=4 and @state=MD`. How can concatenate so 'and ' doesn't appear at the beginning?

Comment: you use Select to make them strings to begin with and then aggregate (or use the join static method other answers have given you)

Answer (score 0):

```
string templ = "{0}={1}";
string _authStr = String.Join("&", formParams.Select(kv => String.Format(templ, kv.Key, kv.Value));
```